# map<string, class> using and couting

Tags: c++, class, maps

I have few maps in my project, which I don't know, how to use or simple said: I don't know how to cout some info from map, which has class attached.

**My code (item.h):**

```
    #ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H


class Item
{
    public:
        int level, durability, damage, armor, weight, grade, sex;
        Item(int _level, int _durability, int _damage, int _armor, int _weight, int _grade, int _sex);
        Item();
        virtual ~Item();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

**code (item.cpp):**

```
#include "include/Item.h"

Item::Item(int _level, int _durability, int _damage, int _armor, int _weight, int _grade, int _sex)
{
    level = _level;
    durability = _durability;
    damage = _damage;
    armor = _armor;
    weight = _weight;
    grade = _grade;
    sex = _sex;
}

Item::Item(): level(0), durability(20), damage(0), armor(0), weight(1), grade(1), sex(0)
{
    //dtor
}

Item::~Item()
{
    //dtor
}
```

**Code (main.cpp):**

```
std::map<std::string, Item> item;

// level, durability, damage, armor, weight, grade, sex
item.insert(std::pair<std::string, Item>("Wooden Sword", Item(1, 19, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0)));
```

How to cout some info from the selected array from map? Tried searching in the google, etc. Can't find answer and explanation why do I get error if I try something like this:

```
cout << item["Wooden Sword"]["level"];
```

for what purpose you can use `item.find("Wooden Sword"); ?`
how does map work with classes? How can I select data from maps which have classes. Really thanks in advance. :) Hope I explained what I want and gave you everything that you need.

Comment: `item["Wooden Sword"]` returns a reference to the `Item` object associated with the key `"Wooden Sword"`. If you want to print the contents of that `Item`, provide an `ostream& operator<<(ostream&&, Item const&)` overload, or if all you want is the level, do `cout << item["Wooden Sword"].level;`

Comment: If you need to specify the field name at runtime, you can add to your `Item` class: `int& operator[](const std::string& fieldname) { if (fieldname == "level") return level; else if (fieldname == "durability") return durability; else ... else throw std::runtime_error("unknown Item field"); }` and/or `int operator[](const std::string& fieldname) const { <same body as above> }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index operator returns a reference to the data element, in your case it returns an `Item&` that you use as a normal structure:

```
std::cout << item["Wooden Sword"].level << '\n';
```

As for the `find` function it returns an iterator. If you don't know about iterators, study them first.

If you want a good reference, see e.g. [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Answer (score 0):

Using `item.find("Wooden Sword");` you get an `iterator` to the matching key/value pair element. If there is no key like "Wooden Sword" it returns `end(item);`. Use `find` if you don't know if the item exists and don't want to add one.

```
auto it = item.find("Wooden Sword");
if (it != end(item))
{
    std::cout << it->level;   // use the -> operator
    // std::string key = it.first; 
    // Item& item = it.second;
}
else
    std::cout << "There is no Wooden Sword";
```

The `[]`operator returns a reference to the matching item. If there is no item associated with this key, a new item will be inserted at this position.

```
std::cout << item["Wooden Sword"].level;
```

Comment: Thanks did not think i can use them like this.